# Run spark SQL on CHD5.4.1 NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: hive, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I setup my `CHD5.4.1` to run some test `Spark SQL` on `Spark`. Spark work well but Spark SQL have some issues.

I start `pyspark` as below:

`/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/lib/spark/bin/pyspark --master yarn-client`

I want to select a table in `Hive` with Spark SQL:
`results = sqlCtx.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table").collect()`

It print error logs: http://pastebin.com/u98psBG8

```
> Welcome to
>       ____              __
>      / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
>     _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/    /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.3.0
>       /_/
> 
> Using Python version 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014 22:59:56)
> SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlCtx.
> >>> results = sqlCtx.sql("SELECT * FROM vt_call_histories").collect() 15/05/20 06:57:07 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with
> implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
> 15/05/20 06:57:07 INFO ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is
> already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the
> same plugin in the classpath. The URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar"
> is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical
> plugin located at URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.2.jar."
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle)
> "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have
> multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar"
> is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical
> plugin located at URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.1.jar."
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle)
> "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont
> have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The
> URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.1.jar"
> is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical
> plugin located at URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2
> unknown - will be ignored 15/05/20 06:57:08 INFO Persistence: Property
> hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 WARN HiveMetaStore: Retrying creating default
> database after error: Error creating transactional connection factory
> javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional
> connection factory   at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)   at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
> at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)  
> at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)  
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:56)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:579)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:557)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:606)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:448)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5601)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1486)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:64)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:74)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2845)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2864)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:453)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:225)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:241)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:240) 
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:86)  
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)   at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)  
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)   at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)  
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
> at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
> at
> org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
> at
> org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:282)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:240)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:286)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
> at
> org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
> at
> org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
> at
> org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
> at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356) 
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)   at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
> at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)  
> at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)  
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:56)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:579)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:557)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:606)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:448)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5601)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1486)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:64)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:74)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2845)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2864)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:453)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:225)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:241)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:240) 
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:86)  
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)   at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)  
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)   at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)  
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
> at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)   at
> org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.loadDriver(AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.java:47)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:54)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:238)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:131)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:85)
> ... 73 more Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation:
> package org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks is sealed   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:388)  
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:417)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)   at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)   at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)   at
> org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getImplementations(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getDefaultImplementations(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.runWithState(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.<init>(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startMonitor(Unknown
> Source)   at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source) 
> at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.boot(Unknown Source)   at
> org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(Unknown Source)   ... 83
> more 15/05/20 06:57:08 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with
> implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 INFO ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is
> already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the
> same plugin in the classpath. The URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar"
> is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical
> plugin located at URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.2.jar."
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle)
> "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have
> multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar"
> is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical
> plugin located at URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.1.jar."
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle)
> "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont
> have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The
> URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.1.jar"
> is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical
> plugin located at URL
> "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
> 15/05/20 06:57:08 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2
> unknown - will be ignored 15/05/20 06:57:08 INFO Persistence: Property
> hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
> <module>   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py",
> line 528, in sql
>     return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 538, in __call__   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
> line 300, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o31.sql. : java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:472)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:225)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:241)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:240) 
> at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:86)  
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)   at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)  
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)   at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)  
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1488)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:64)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:74)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2845)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2864)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:453)
> ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1486)
> ... 21 more Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error
> creating transactional connection factory NestedThrowables:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)   at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)   at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
> at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)  
> at
> javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)  
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:56)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:579)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:557)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:610)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:448)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5601)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
> ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
> at
> org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
> at
> org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:282)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:240)
> at
> org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:286)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
> at
> org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
> at
> org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
> at
> org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
> at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356) 
> at
> org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
> ... 55 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
> initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer for my problem.

After CDH 5.3 is installed and Spark is enabled through Cloudera Manager, follow these steps to enable Hive access:

1. Ensure hive is working from Hive CLI and JDBC through HiveServer2 (Should be working by default).
2. Copy hive-site.xml to your SPARK_HOME/conf folder.
3. Add Hive libraries to Spark classpath -> edit the SPARK_HOME/bin/compute-classpath.sh file and add the following:
   CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/hive/lib/*" (CDH specific example, use your hive lib location).
4. Restart the Spark cluster for everything to take effect.

[Read full document here](https://github.com/abhibasu/sparksql/wiki/SparkSQL-Configuration-in-CDH-5.3)

Comment: I had the same issue... CDH 5.4.1, Spark 1.3.1.
SparkSql does not work... For me, Step 2 was the only required step.

Comment: Also, need to add that I had to copy the hive-site.xml file on ALL spark nodes

Comment: I had the same problem and with step 2 it was resolved ! Thanks !
CDH 5.4.8, Parcels

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem and found out that the REAL problem was hive libraries clashing with spark libraries. If you look at your logs above -

```
15/05/20 06:57:08 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is
already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the
same plugin in the classpath. The URL
"file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.2.jar.
```

That is not a harmless warning. That is the core of the problem. I had hive jars already in my CLASSPATH. I removed them and started Spark and everything went fine. So - try ONLY that first. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9198

The bit about copying the hive-site.xml is needed if you get an error like `Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D`

I ended up in having a hive-site.xml like below

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>blah</description>
</property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/<yourusername></value>
  <description>blah</description>  
</property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/<yourusername></value>
  <description>blah</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/<yourusername></value>
  <description>blah</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.scratch.dir.permission</name>
    <value>733</value>
  <description>blah</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.querylog.location</name>
    <value>/tmp/<yourusername></value>
  <description>blah</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name>
    <value>/tmp/<yourusername>/operation_logs</value>
  <description>blah</description>
  </property>
```

I removed everything else from the hive-site.xml. See [java.net.URISyntaxException when starting HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099898/java-net-urisyntaxexception-when-starting-hive)

Answer (score 0):

also you can set the hive config when running spark-submit 
this is ok for me in cdh 5.4.5

```
spark-submit \  
--class com.xxx.main.TagHive \
--master yarn-client \
--name HiveTest \
--num-executors 3 \
--driver-memory 500m \
--executor-memory 500m \
--executor-cores 1 \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/etc/hive/conf:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/*.jar" \
--files ./log4j-spark.properties \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-spark.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-spark.properties" \
dmp-tag-etl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar $1 $2
```