# Unable to launch hive with mysql metastore

Tags: mysql, hive, bigdata

When I use hive with derby metastore, it works fine. I want to use mysql metastore so I followed this link {https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-mysql-metastore}.

Now when I launch hive by typing "hive" command on terminal I get many errors i.e.

> {Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient}
>
> {Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url =
>   jdbc:mysql://usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/metastore_db?
>   createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, username = hive_user}
>
> {com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure}

Please suggest me something.

Comment: The JDBC URL looks very wrong. It should be something like 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore', or with the hostname instead of localhost if mysql is on another host. Look in hive-site.xml and change the URL to the correct one.

Comment: Thanks robert, I will try it once reach home :)

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your help. It worked. Anyway after your suggestion, I got one more error like

${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
 but I resolved them by changing some properties values in hive-site.xml. The solution was present here {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099898/java-net-urisyntaxexception-when-starting-hive}

Comment: I am trying to configure mysql with hive from a very very long time, Everytime I encounter errors I don't understand where I am going wrong ..... as you can see in this link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb86629116891e5b2d8c30b95aca9aee

hive-site.xml configuration can be seen here in the link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44f1c9fc214136a113067cf3b4b72794